# What's wrong with my VirtualHost?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have the following VirtualHost

```
// filename: /etc/apache2/sites-available/ccbbbcc

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
     ServerAdmin utopia@ccbbbcc.com
     ServerName ccbbbcc.com
     ServerAlias www.ccbbbcc.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/ccbbbcc/production/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/ccbbbcc/production/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/ccbbbcc/production/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And then I also have

```
//filename: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
blah blah blah
```

**How come when I type into my browser http://1.1.1.1, it takes me to http://ccbbbcc.com ?   Even when I point new urls to the IP 1.1.1.1, webpages serve from http://ccbbbcc.com.  Why am I unable to serve pages from /var/www directory?**

Additional symptoms - the ccbbbcc vhost overrides only SOME of my other vhosts. Not all.

### Additional Notes

I've made sure to use a2ensite and to restart apache.

This is what my /etc/apache2/ports.conf looks like

```
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

I made a file called /srv/www/ccbbbcc/production/public_html/test.html with the text "Hello World".  When I type http://ccbbbcc.com/test.html, the page loads fine.   When I type http://1.1.1.1/test.html, I get a 404 Page Not Found.  When I type http://1.1.1.1/, the web browser refreshes and then displays the url http://ccbbbcc.com.  I then append test.html to the end of the url, and the Hello World shows up again.

So does that mean there's an http redirect happening somewhere?  If so, I can't seem to determine what's causing it.

Also, i notice ccbbbcc overrides SOME of my virtualhosts, not ALL.  There doesn't seem to be a pattern to which vhost is discriminated/overridden.

I also noticed that if I do the following

```
1. a2dissite ccbbbcc
2. /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
3. a2ensite ccbbbcc
4. /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Then all of a sudden, http://ccbbbcc.com serves pages from /var/www/, and http://1.1.1.1 also serves pages from /var/www.  How come the a2ensite/a2dissite of affects where pages are loaded from?  The only way to make ccbbbcc serve pages from /srv/www/cbs/production again is to reboot my entire linux server!  What's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can read in [An In-Depth Discussion of Virtual Host Matching](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html):

> The first vhost on this list (the
>   first vhost in the config file with
>   the specified IP address) has the
>   highest priority and catches any
>   request to an unknown server name or a
>   request without a Host: header field.

Your Apache httpd loads and evaluates the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/ccbbbcc` before `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.

Rename `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` for example to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/00_default` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/ccbbbcc` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/01_ccbbbcc`, so that the default file is loaded first.

Comment: Apache has several configuration files, what 'config file' to check for the 'vhost list' in this context? I assume it's "/etc/apache2/sites-available"?

Comment: OK, I seem have figured it out, there is a line in my apache3.conf: `Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`, and when I `ls` that directory the first item appeared is the fist `vhost`....

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a NameVirtualHost directive?

See here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

Basically if you don't have a NameVirtualHost *, or specific NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80 directive, the virtual host isn't Name-Based, it's address:port based.

Comment: I have NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80
Listen 80
Listen 443
 in my ports.conf

Comment: How are your symlinks in sites-enabled configured?  They are sourced alphabetically and I am not sure, but Apache may default to the first VirtualHost directive for the host:port combination.

Comment: I'm don't understand the symlinks.  How do I check?  Also, I think I noticed the alphabetical ordering of VirtualHost file names influencing which host:port combination gets selected.  But shouldn't the ServerName property make the selection more specific/filtered?

Answer (score 1):

Without a ServerName/ServerAlias block in your virtual hosts, apache will serve the domain first instantiated during the config read.  In this case, alphabetically, ccbbbccc.com's config file must come before default.

Add ServerName and/or ServerAlias directives in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default and you should be set.

Comment: Thanks, I did this but still no effect.  I noticed that under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ there's a file called 000-default.  Apparently apache automatically renames my default to 000-default to ensure it gets loaded first.

Comment: can you post the results of:

/usr/sbin/apache2 -S

Comment: Hmm...I get a "apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}".  What does that mean?

Comment: did you install apache from a package? or compile it yourself?  After you are making config changes, are you stopping apache, ps ax|grep apache, make sure it is stopped, then restarting it?  in your config file, User   should correspond to a value, is there a username on your system that corresponds?