# virtual hosts overlapping in debian apache2

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have a domain **domain.com** and a subdomain **sub.domain.com** .

In apache2/sites-available I have 2 vhosts files: **domain** and **sub**.

When I do **a2ensite sub** the subdomain overwrites the domain, so when I go to see the main domain I see the content for the subdomain. WHen the subdomain is added both the domain and the subdomain point to the subdomain.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the vhosts

**DOMAIN**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/domain/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
# in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
#            RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

**SUBDOMAIN**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName sub.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/sub/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
# in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
#            RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not read the configuration files yet. But I would like you to definitely go and check /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Is sub-domain linked with a number **before** the *domain.com*?

example 010-sub links to /etc/apache2/subdomain.conf

and 020-sub links to /etc/apache2/domain.conf

so that Apache will parse first subdomain.conf given a request.

Comment: no they are not. can I add manually the priority number?

Comment: renaming them in sites-available and reloading them worked for the moment. another resource on the issue here. http://serverfault.com/questions/132770/whats-wrong-with-my-virtualhost

Comment: So I assume your issue is solved, what you can do is rm a file and ln -s ... it again